# Showing record count in DevExpress XtraGrid v12.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview, xtragrid

Below is part of my base `EntityList` class which contains a grid. The grid will be filled with columns and rows depending on child entities later. I need to show the number of rows on the grid's footer, and thus I am using `TotalSummary`.

```
<dx:ASPxGridView runat="server" ID="grdMain" ClientInstanceName="grid" 
        KeyFieldName="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false">                                   
    <settings showfooter="True"/>
    <TotalSummary>
        <dx:ASPxSummaryItem FieldName="ID" SummaryType="Count"/>
    </TotalSummary>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

The problem is, in different entities that use this base class, I have different names for the `ID` column, such as `InvoiceID`, `CustomerID`, etc. So, how to tell the grid what `Count` I want it to show? Even if I had the same name for the specified column, that column would not be visible in the grid, thus it's `TotalSummaryItem` showing the count of that column, would not be seen on the grid.

Is there any way to tell the grid I need it to show the `Count` of rows, not a specified column with a fixed name?

Any ideas how to solve this problem??? Many thanks!

P.S. if it helps, I am implementing `IListServer` in a `DataObject` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for `FieldName` property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxSummaryItem_FieldNametopic) does not tell anything about this, but it says something important that can help solve the problem.

By using [`Custom`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressDataSummaryItemTypeEnumtopic) for the value of [`SummaryType`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxSummaryItem_SummaryTypetopic) property and handling [`CustomSummaryCalculate`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_CustomSummaryCalculatetopic) event, you have complete control over how the summary item is being calculated. Handle the event and count the rows, however you want.

Another option is to add the summary item in code, where you know the name of the columns. I guess when you are creating the grid and supplying its data, you can find the name of the desired column.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still need to bind the Custom summary to a column:

`<dx:ASPxSummaryItem FieldName="???" SummaryType="Custom"/>`

Comment: What happens when you leave it empty?

Comment: Still nothing happends. `Field Name` has to be filled with an existing field name.